# Unsubscribe link shows all groups in Civicrm

Tags: groups, mosaico, unsubscribe

When an email recipients clicks on the unsubscribe link in a Mosaico email, every group in Civi is revealed. EG *Are you sure you want to be removed from the mailing list(s) shown below: 100 plus groups appear* This happens whether the person is subscribed to all of the groups or not. Is there a way to ensure that they just see the group that they are subscribed to? Some of the information revealed is potentially sensitive.

Comment: are you using civicrm unsubscribe link token? or have your own one?

Comment: are you saying that a logged out user, using the link, sees groups that are not set to Public? and can you update your question with an anonymised version of the url they end up at

Comment: Hi Peter, I think it has been fixed. I believe that all our groups were mailing lists and they were all set to public, whether they were relevant to the person getting the email or not. The unsubscribe link is the standard Mosaico link. The URL they arrive at is xxxx.org.au/civi/?civiwp=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fmailing%2Funsubscribe&reset=1&jid=868&qid=12153&h=f5d3d089b2114ace.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using the GDPR extension to manage group subscriptions. The extension will provide finer grained control of which groups are displayed and how they are shown to subscribers etc.

Comment: Thanks Parvez. I will give it a go.